# Using multiple keywords with LIKE in Postgresql through Spring Data JPA

Tags: spring, postgresql, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I need to define a JPA query that translates as:

```
SELECT
  *
from 
  items_table
where
  lower(CONCAT(item_id,' ', color,' ',details,' ')) like all ('{"%blue%", "%plastic%"}') and 
  store='Main' and 
  status='In Stock' and 
  item_type='Container';
```

the parameter list in all will be an input along with the store, status and item_type from the front end.

Comment: How is the question related to json[] data type columns?

Comment: @crizzis extremely sorry for that.

Answer (score 0):

I understand it's the first `WHERE` condition you're having a problem with. If a `String[]`-typed parameter doesn't cut it, try using [this approach](https://vladmihalcea.com/bind-custom-hibernate-parameter-type-jpa-query/), hopefully the `LIKE ALL` will pass through to the generated query - sth like:

```
@Query("SELECT i FROM Item i WHERE LOWER(CONCAT(...)) LIKE ALL :terms AND ...")
List<Item> findByTerms(TypedParameterValue terms, ...)


itemRepository.findByTerms(new TypedParameterValue(StringArrayType.INSTANCE, terms), ...)
```

If it turns out JPA doesn't like `LIKE ALL`, you'll have to keep using the native query.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, while trying to implement this I got another error, will try to solve that and then try this.

Comment: Thanks, your approach is working with a string array but I am encountering another error: 
ERROR: op ANY/ALL (array) requires array on right side. Please let me know if you know the probable cause of this.

Comment: It's a postgres error, so it seems `LIKE ALL` passes through successfully. I understand that you're passing a `String[]` into terms? What if you surround `:terms` with brackets: `LIKE ALL (:terms)`?